# Variable in generator function shadows name from outer scope

Tags: python, scope, generator

I recently started to teach myself Python and currently work on generator functions. Here, I encountered a "scoping" issue with variable names inside of the generator shadowing names in outer scope. I did some research on this but could not come up with an explanation.

Given this minimal example:

```
def do_stuff(var):
    shadow = var * var

def dummy_generator(size):
    for i in range(size):
        do_stuff(i)
        yield i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for shadow in dummy_generator(5):
        print(shadow)
```

PyCharm emits the warning "Shadows name 'shadow' from outer scope" for 'shadow' in the do_stuff function (I'm using Python 3.10.9 on Linux).

I would like to understand why this is the case.

Comment: It just means `shadow` from global scope can't be used in your `do_stuff` function. The `shadow` in `do_stuff` is a separate variable.

Comment: Well, technically it does: if you put `print(shadow)` in `do_stuff`, you'll get the value of the local variable, not the global variable. It's a fairly useless warning, though: the entire *point* of having local namespaces is to allow this kind of shadowing, and it's not (IMO) worth providing specific warnings about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard is just an ordinary `if` statement. If statements don't introduce a new scope, so the statements in its body are evaluated in the surrounding (global) scope. Hence the loop

```
for shadow in dummy_generator(5):
```

is assigning to the *global variable* `shadow`.

When you then write `shadow = var * var` inside `do_stuff`, you're introducing a local variable `shadow` that is shadowing the global variable `shadow`. Any further uses of `shadow` in `do_stuff` would resolve to that local variable as opposed to the global variable. This *could* be indicative of a mistake in your code (maybe you thought you were accessing the global `shadow` when really you're using the local variable), or at very least can be confusing to people reading your code, which is why PyCharm is emitting are warning for it.

Comment: That was the missing link, thank you. We are still in global scope - that is still somewhat confusing for me.